# SVG in Fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, svg, fancybox

I need svg image in fancybox.

```html
<div id="data">
  <svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
  </svg>
  <img src="http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/260/e/1/circle_png_by_xdicsii-d4a2odp.png" />
  <a id="inline" href="#data" style="margin-left:15px;">Full Screen</a>
</div>
```

I want to get full screen of the div with id "data".

When i click on "Full Screen" i'm getting full screen of div with id"data" with jpg images, but not the svg image(Which is rendered into the div)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height:inherit; width:inherit"></div>
```